# Intellij does not open existing projects after update

Tags: intellij-idea

I updated to Intellij 2018.3.5 today and now it wont open any of my previous projects that are .idea based. In the logs I can see the following. This was working fine with 2018.3.4.

This appears to happen only in Ubuntu not in Windows.

```
2019-03-07 14:58:06,594 [ 246696]   INFO - roject.impl.ProjectManagerImpl - Fatal error initializing plugin com.intellij.uiDesigner 
com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing plugin com.intellij.uiDesigner
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:253)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:504)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectImpl.init(ProjectImpl.java:264)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.initProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:285)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.loadProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:314)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.loadProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:306)
    at com.intellij.projectImport.ProjectOpenProcessorBase.doOpenProject(ProjectOpenProcessorBase.java:197)
    at com.intellij.ide.impl.ProjectUtil.openOrImport(ProjectUtil.java:137)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.OpenFileAction.doOpenFile(OpenFileAction.java:111)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.OpenFileAction.lambda$prepareFileChooserAndOpen$1(OpenFileAction.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.ex.FileChooserDialogImpl.choose(FileChooserDialogImpl.java:145)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.FileChooser.chooseFiles(FileChooser.java:114)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.FileChooser.chooseFiles(FileChooser.java:91)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.OpenFileAction.prepareFileChooserAndOpen(OpenFileAction.java:58)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.OpenFileAction.lambda$actionPerformed$0(OpenFileAction.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:435)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:403)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:719)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:668)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:363)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Could not initialize class java.awt.dnd.DragSource [Plugin: com.intellij.uiDesigner]
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.dnd.DragSource
    at com.intellij.ide.palette.impl.PaletteWindow.<init>(PaletteWindow.java:75)
    at com.intellij.ide.palette.impl.PaletteToolWindowManager.<init>(PaletteToolWindowManager.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:85)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:62)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:462)
    ... 36 more
2019-03-07 14:58:39,041 [ 279143]   WARN - roject.impl.ProjectManagerImpl - Fatal error initializing plugin com.intellij.uiDesigner 
com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing plugin com.intellij.uiDesigner
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:253)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:504)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectImpl.init(ProjectImpl.java:264)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.initProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:285)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.newProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.intellij.projectImport.ProjectOpenProcessorBase.doOpenProject(ProjectOpenProcessorBase.java:204)
    at com.intellij.ide.impl.ProjectUtil.openOrImport(ProjectUtil.java:137)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.OpenFileAction.doOpenFile(OpenFileAction.java:111)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.OpenFileAction.lambda$prepareFileChooserAndOpen$1(OpenFileAction.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.ex.FileChooserDialogImpl.choose(FileChooserDialogImpl.java:145)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.FileChooser.chooseFiles(FileChooser.java:114)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.FileChooser.chooseFiles(FileChooser.java:91)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.OpenFileAction.prepareFileChooserAndOpen(OpenFileAction.java:58)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.OpenFileAction.lambda$actionPerformed$0(OpenFileAction.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:435)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:403)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:719)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:668)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:363)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Could not initialize class java.awt.dnd.DragSource [Plugin: com.intellij.uiDesigner]
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.dnd.DragSource
    at com.intellij.ide.palette.impl.PaletteWindow.<init>(PaletteWindow.java:75)
    at com.intellij.ide.palette.impl.PaletteToolWindowManager.<init>(PaletteToolWindowManager.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:85)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:62)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:462)
    ... 35 more
2019-03-07 14:59:20,708 [ 320810]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Terminating: 17961/Maven3ServerImpl9b795730 
2019-03-07 14:59:20,721 [ 320823]   INFO -           #cursive.repl.server - Shutting down local REPL
```

Comment: caused by `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.dnd.DragSource`. Please try deleting the installation and re-installing from scratch - looks as if the installation is broken

Comment: Okay so it does open after I reinstall but I had quite a lot of settings which are all now gone. It is a lost couple of hours it would have been great if the in place update worked in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA reinstall will fix this problem.

You can reinstall without removing the [IDE folders](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) with the configuration, only the installation folder.

This way all your settings will be preserved. You can also use [IDE Settings Sync](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html) plug-in to keep your settings in the JetBrains account and easily backup/sync them between the machines.

Another option is to use the [Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/) app for the seamless updates which also supports reverting to the previous version if something goes wrong.